# Java tools for Concurrent XML Editing

Tags: java, xml, concurrency, editing

I am building a user interface where users must be able to concurrently make edits on a web page. The standard technique employed in 90+% of our application is optimistic locking; that is, we expect that concurrent edits will open happen very rarely, and if they do, the second committer gets an error and loses their edit.

In limited parts of the application, concurrent edits are expected, and we need to handle them in a better way. Locking to force sequential editing is not an option, as it would require a timeout on the lock for the situation where a user walks away from their screen without explicitly unlocking, which would be very annoying.

If possible, I would like to hold the form data as XML, but to allow concurrent edits to this document to be made.

Some tools I have briefly looked into that may be able to do this, or provide some inspiration in how best to handle it are:

Apache Wave (Google Wave) http://incubator.apache.org/wave/

MobWrite http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/

Does anyone have some more suggestions of toolkits or techniques that could handle this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Two basic algorithms can help you here:

**1. [Operational transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation), which is behind Apache Wave.**

The main idea is to capture elementary editing events and merge concurrent event streams from different users. Although  simple at the first glance, this approach may require complex implementation:

1. Robust cross-browser capturing and decomposition of all editing events may be tricky to implement
2. There's no easy way to restore synchronized state of several communication agents in case of network errors/timeouts.

**2. [Differential sync](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/), which is behind Google Mobwrite.**

This one is based on computing a diff between edited copy and some base state, so called "shadow". Concurrent diffs are then getting merged. One can easily compute a diff between any two arbitrary states of the document, so there's no problem to recover from the sync package loss. The following [tech talks record](https://neil.fraser.name/news/2009/01/11/) explains this technique in details.

Facing the requirement similar to yours, I've based my solution on the second approach due to it's simplicity and robustness. Original Mobwrite implementation uses a Python backend, so I've reimplemented it in Java. You can find a working prototype [here](https://github.com/jk1/collaborative-editor), it's a simple web-based collaborative editor I made as a proof-of-concept before adopting the same approach in our proprietary software.

Comment: Nice work, I've starred your project on GitHub. Operational Transformation is overkill for my requirements. What I need to merge is a list of items, computing the diff is easy using the "relative difference" between two lists as sets. Relative diff one way around gives the things added, the other way around, the things removed.